# Get full path of script in PATH environment variable

Tags: terminal, bash

I was wondering if there is a built-in command in Bash (or even something OSX-specific) that would display the fully resolved path of a script that is in the current `PATH` environment variable.

For example, my `PATH` currently looks like this:

```
>: echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n"
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/opt/X11/bin
/Users/Josh/Dropbox/Scripts/Bash
/Users/Josh/Dropbox/Tools/WinRAR/OSX
```

And there's a script in Dropbox called `get-azurelogs.sh`. That path is in my `PATH` variable for convenience, but if I wanted to display the complete path to that script, assuming I wasn't sure where it was, is there an simple one-liner way to display the fully resolved path instead of testing it at each of the directories above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `which`.  From the man page:

> The which utility takes a list of command names and searches the path for each executable file that would be run had these commands actually been invoked

Comment: Boom. I knew there had to be something. Will accept the answer as soon as the mandatory waiting period is up. Thanks!

Comment: whoops, didn't see your answer initially. cheers!

Answer (score 4):

A good alternative to `which` is the builtin `type`. The advantage being that `type` is also able to handle bash aliases and functions.

Comment: There's also `type -P` which restricts itself to executables on disk only - no aliases are shown.

Answer (score 2):

```
which -a [nameofexecutable]
```

IE:

```
Macbook-Pro:~ njboot$ which -a chmod 
/bin/chmod
Macbook-Pro:~ njboot$ which -a nusers
/Users/njboot/bin/nusers
```